# Can I use string "IsEmpty" methods in Delphi

Tags: delphi, string

Embaracdero documents ["IsEmpty" methods](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__WideString__IsEmpty.html) for string types, which I've used successfully with C++ Builder code.

```
WideString s;

if (s.IsEmpty())
   ....
```

I tried the same from Delphi, and couldn't get it to compile:

```
var s: WideString;
begin
  if s.IsEmpty then
  ....
```

I know you can compare with an empty string, or call the Length function, but is it possible to call this IsEmpty method from Delphi?

EDIT: Just to clarify, this wasn't meant as a String vs Widestring issue.

Basically, the docs I link to above describe a Pascal syntax, as well as a C++ one, yet this doesn't seem to work. I assume this is just a flaw in the documentation.

*Returns true if the System::WideString::WideString is empty.*

**Pascal:** function IsEmpty: bool;

Comment: What does the C++ implementation look like?

Comment: You may not think it's a WideString vs. string issue, but it is.

Comment: @Craig - The question shouldn't involve strings, only WideStrings. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It involved strings before you edited the question to remove them.

Comment: @Craig - Yup, can't argue with that....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String is not a class in Delphi therefore it has no methods, you have to use functions for string manipulations like Length, Copy, etc... String is a class in C++ so maybe you are confused by that.

Comment: Thanks. That's the heart of it: String types are all classes in C++, but not in Delphi. The Codegear documentation is wrong to list pascal equivalents to these methods.

Comment: MY guess is that the Pascal equivalents in the help probably refer to Delphi.NET where Strings *are* classes... (haven't checked this myself yet)

Comment: Yes, Delphi documentation is all messed up in these versions but at least CodeGear is trying to gather something better via updates.

Answer (score 5):

No. string is not WideString, even in D2009. You wouldn't want to, either; comparing with nil/empty string is much faster than a method call.

In Delphi:

```
var 
  s: string;
begin
  if s = '' then begin
    ShowMessage('It is empty or nil.');
```

...for string detects both nil and empty string (which is = nil).

Comment: Okaayyyy. I get this:
[DCC Error] Unit69.pas(31): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Pointer'
What am I doing wrong? (this with D2007, by the way.)

Comment: Error in my example. Fixed. The point is that Delphi actually compares with nil under the hood (look at disassembly).

Comment: You can compare (and NEED to compare) strings with nil in Delphi.Net. In native Delphi, it's enough to compare with EmptyStr or '' .

Comment: In .NET, use string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 5):

Delphi is an hybrid language. It contains basic types and classes. Only classes (and records and objects) can contain methods.

String is a basic type, although a special one. It's the only type that has a reserved word. That's why its often written with a lowercase (string) unlike other types which have a starting captial (Integer).

You can if you like:

```
type
  TString = class
  private
    FString: string;
  public
    constructor Create(const AValue: string);

    property &String: string read FString write FString;
    property IsEmpty: Boolean read GetIsEmpty;
    // ...
  end;
```

Comment: You can prefix a reserved word (like string or while) with a & to use it as a normal identifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
if Trim(s)='' then
```

???

Comment: I know there are other ways. I want to know if IsEmpty can actually be used.

Comment: function IsEmpty(s:string):boolean; begin;   result:=length(s)=0; end; Now you can use it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the new editions you can use many string helper functions and s.IsEmpty too.