# How to set empty value to excel specific cell in delphi?

Tags: excel, delphi

As title, there are some solution I had tried, but all of them didn't work.

```
XLApp.Application.cells[1, 1].Value := '';

XLApp.Application.cells[1, 1].Value := nil;

XLApp.Application.cells[1, 1].Value := EmptyParam;
```

Comment: Try `XLApp.Application.cells[1, 1].Clear`

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017469/empty-strings-in-delphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variant value that can be used to clear the contents of a cell is `Unassigned`.

```
Cells[1,1].Value := Unassigned;
```

Alternatively you can use the `Clear` method on a cell.

```
Cells[1,1].Clear;
```

Personally I find the latter to be more readable.

Comment: Thx, David:). By the way, It looks like "XLApp.ActiveSheet.cells[1, 1].ClearContents;" is available too.